# Can I remove all duplicates (not only consecutive) to put my histories (.bash_history, .gdb_history) under version control?

Tags: bash, git, version-control, hook

I have this mantra:

> If it's plain text and it is valuable, put it under version control.

So far I have the following under git:

1. My editor (Emacs/Spacemacs) configuration.
2. My bash configuration
3. Various todo lists

I have created a repo to store my histories, but I have come across the issue of having duplicates in them.

To me it is pretty disappointing that `HISTCONTROL=erasedups` only deals with consecutive duplicates.

Would it be possible to create a hook that is executed every time I enter a new command to remove duplicates in the histories?

Or should it be a pre push git hook each time I push to the repo?

Comment: `cat -N .bash_history newhistory | sort -usk2 | sort -nk1,1 | cut -f2-`

Comment: I would remove the duplicates just before committing (not before pushing, as it'd be too late!).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Yes! I didn't realize that. Thank you!